# Problems with DataBase Android

Tags: android

I have a big problem with my Database.

This is the code I used to have to create the DataBase:

```
public static void initDatabase(Context context){
    db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (number TEXT, name TEXT);");
    db.close();
    Log.i(TAG, "Database opened ok"); 
}
```

The problem is that now, I need to add a new table with new information.
If I create a new table the same way, I have problems with my application cause when it try to access the DataBase, it breaks.

Can anyone help me?? I don´t know very well how to make correctly the database in Android.

EDITED:

This is the code of the new table....

```
public static void initDatabase(Context context){
db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
        TABLE_NAME + " (tlf TEXT, name TEXT);");
db.close();
Log.i(TAG, "Database opened ok");
```

}

This is why i didn´t added it before, cause it is another table which is almost the same as the other one....

EDITED AND SOLVED:

It was necessary to use the `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)` method from SQLiteOpenHelper class to be able to be able to update my database table.
For more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Thanks anyway to everyone!

Comment: Please share the code that adds the new table and the error in LogCat

Comment: Please put the solution in it's own answer and accept it, so that this question can move out of the unanswered tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to use the onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) method from SQLiteOpenHelper class to be able to be able to update my database table.

For more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html